# javascript how to foreach loop through an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have an array that look like this

```
var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"]
```

I want to foreach loop through the array and extract each of the ids and pass that into ajax. so it will auto fill in some input field

I am familiar with PHP where I would use

```
foreach($array as $temporaryvariable){
  // do stuff with $temporaryvariable
}
```

so I am looking for a Javascript or JQuery equivalent, so my final code will look something like the below

```
var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"]

foreach(ids as id){
$.ajax({
  url: "../folder/lookupserver.php",
  type: "POST", 
  data: {
    'id' : id//each of the ids
  },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success:function(data){
    $result= data;
    $('#input field').val($result);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use `forEach()` to loop through the array, however I see two issues. Firstly bombarding your server with several requests quickly is not a great idea - it's basically DDOSing yourself. Make one request with all data and return a single response. Also, if you're only updating one field, only the final result will be shown, which makes all previous requests redundant.

Comment: Why would you want to execute ajax queries in a loop?  You should pass all the `ids` in one query to your `lookupserver.php`, and have it return one result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A better, less server intensive way would be to pass...

The whole array to server,

```
var ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"];

$.ajax({
    url: "../folder/lookupserver.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {

        'id': ids
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        $result = data;
        $('#input field').val($result);
    }
});
```

then read the array in `PHP` and use a `foreach` to get the individual ID's like that.

This way you aren't sending so many requests in rapid successions to the server.

### However...

If you really want to send that many requests, you'd use a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

```
var ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"];

ids.forEach(function (id) {
    /** Your AJAX request here. **/
});
```

Comment: it's better than his 4 AJAX requests but the initial question is "how to foreach loop through an array" ...

Comment: @Ivan I provided a better solution which is perfectly acceptable too.

Comment: @Ivan the initial question is often a corollary to the actual issue. You should always guide the OP towards the best solution for their use case - even if it's not what they specifically asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```js
var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"]
ids.forEach(function(id) {

  console.log(id);
  // here you can have an AJAX

});
```

This methods takes one parameter: a function, that will be executed for each element of the array. You need to specify the name you want to call each element you select. Like you would in PHP: `foreach($ids as $id)`

Comment: How do you plan on dealing with all the AJAX requests updating only a single field?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am only showing how to use `forEach()`. The use of multiple AJAX requests is another thing...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop for that

```
var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"]
var id;
    for(var i=0; i< ids.length;i++){
       id = ids[i];
       $.ajax({
            url: "../folder/lookupserver.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: {

                   'id' : id//each of the ids
             },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success:function(data){
                           $result= data;
                           $('#input field').val($result);
                                }

         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays also have a foreach function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Try something like

```
var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"].foreach( function(element, index) {
    // custom ajax code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript this would be a for loop like so

Example :

```
  var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"]

  var i;

  for(i in ids){

        //do whatever here

}
```

Comment: You can do `for (var i in ids)` too.

Answer (score 0):

It's been brought to my attention that I should mention I'm using es6 syntax in this solution. Including object enhancement, arrow functions and the `const` keyword. Be sure to read up on these subjects before using this code in your own projects.

```
const ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"];

const options = id => ({ 
  url: '../folder/lookupserver.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { id },
  dataType: 'JSON'
});

const update = data => $('#update field').val(data);

const request = id => $.ajax(options(id)).done(update);

ids.forEach(request);
```

Comment: Why are you defining everything as `const`?

Comment: It signifies a read only reference, informing other developers that you have no intentions on rebinding that variable else where.

Comment: I know what it signifies but who says any of them have to be read-only? I highly doubt the `ids` would be read-only.

Comment: No one did, but `const` should be used by default. That way no one has to guess what might happen later.

Comment: In this case the OP seems rather inexperienced with JavaScript, so what if they used this code and it causes them issues? You could reference `const` in your answer and give a little bit of background about it?

Comment: Ya you're right, thats a good point.

Answer (score -1):

```
var ids = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"];
    i=0;
    $(ids).each(function(){
      console.log(ids[i]);
      i++;
    });
```

Comment: Why define `i` when it already gets defined in the callback?

Comment: Then how you get the index of the array

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote.

Comment: What's the value do you get

Comment: @AbdulRahumanM like @Script47 said, it is already defined. You just have to do  `$(ids).each(function(index, value) { console.log(value); });`.  Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for more information on `.each`